# Graphql client is not accessing default graphql api response of magento 2.3, "Exception#0(GraphQL\\Error\\Error): Type \"int\" not found in document."

Tags: php, graphql, magento-2.3

I have installed magento 2.3 on php 7.2 and ubuntu 16 and wanted to test graphql api from browser graphql client for e.g :-

Url :- http://localhost/magento2/graphql

```
{
  category (
   id: 2
) {
    id
    level
    name
    breadcrumbs {
      category_id
      category_name
      category_level
      category_url_key
    }
  }
}
```

but i am getting error :- `Exception #0 (GraphQL\Error\Error): Type "int" not found in document`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, you are missing important details, like what exactly needs to be done to reproduce the situation. Please also consider extracting a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a typo in your schema definition! you should use '**Int**' not '**int**'!